# JSON file versioning

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am using a json file to load some delivery address in my project.This file is getting updated by the client for several time.But whenever I put the new json file to my project location, it takes too many refresh to reflect the newly added address on the browser even sometime I need to clear the browser cache to reflect properly.
I am using Asp.Net MVC4 .Could I control the version of this JSON file using bundle and minification property so that it gets reflected whenever any change will be made?
Or without using bundling,is there any another process so that it can reflects easily with a single refreash.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following code fragment worked best for me. Since it uses 'require' to load the package.json, it works regardless the current working directory.

```
var pjson = require('./package.json');
console.log(pjson.version);
```

Comment: How do I use it?ryt now I am using by ajax request.